# Calculate and push fibonacci numbers in an array

Tags: javascript

```
let result = [];
function recurseFivonaci(n){
  if(n < 2){
    return n;
  }
  return recurseFivonaci(n - 2) + recurseFivonaci(n - 1);
}

console.log(recurseFivonaci(10).map(r => result.push(r)))
```

```
TypeError: recurseFivonaci(...).map is not a function
    at <anonymous>:16:33
    at dn (<anonymous>:16:5449)
```

How can I push in the result of fibonacci function into an array?

I expect this to work but doesn't:

```
result = [0,1,1,2,...];
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible solution

```js
let result=[];
    
function fibonacci_series(n) 
{
  if(n === 0){
     return [0];
  }
  if (n===1) 
  {
    return [0, 1];
  } 
  else 
  {
    result = fibonacci_series(n - 1);
    result.push(result[result.length - 1] + result[result.length - 2]);
    return result;
  }
};
    
console.log(fibonacci_series(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

[Map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is a function available on an `Array` type in JavaScript and since you're returning a number from your function, it is throwing this error. What you need instead is something like:

```js
let result=[];

function recurseFibonaci (n) {
  if(n < 2){
    return n;
  }
  return recurseFibonaci(n-2) + recurseFibonaci(n-1);
}

result.push(recurseFibonaci(10));
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be some neato means to achieve it but a basic iteration seems fine?

```js
const arr = [0,1]
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  arr.push(arr[i] + arr[i + 1]);
}
console.log(arr);
```